# Exibir uma imagem blob em JS

Tags: javascript, firebird, back-end

Preciso exibir imagens que estão salvas no banco de dados (firebird) em Blob e não estou conseguindo ir a diante com isto.

é retornado uma function do BD

[image: function]

esta function é lida conforme a função a baixo.

daqui em diante precisaria retornar a imagem pelo (res.json) para meu front-end ou salvar esta imagem em um diretório.

```
    router.get("/vitrineGrid",function(req,res){

    query = "SELECT ID, IMAGEM from FOTOS";

    connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
      if(err) {
        res.json({"Error" : true, "Message" : "Error executing query"});
      } else {
        rows[0].IMAGEM(function(err, name, eventEmitter) {
          eventEmitter.on('data', function(chunk) {
            //reading
            console.log(chunk); // buffer da print
          });
          eventEmitter.on('end', function() {
            // end reading
          });
        });
        res.json({"Error" : false, "Message" : "Success", "fotos" : rows});
      }
      connection.detach();
    });
  });
```

[image: log do buffer]

Comment: Você precisa usar a API de arquivos do HTML5, em português veja este post https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/file/dndfiles/